# Are lunchbox contents determined at time of opening?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I just got a notification in-app that Santa and Elf themed costumes are available in lunch boxes for a limited time.

Will lunchboxes that I saved up prior to this notification have a possibility of containing these limited time rewards?

If I purchase a lunchbox but open it after the "limited time", could it still have a Santa/Elf costume?

Comment: I don't think anyone but a developer can answer that question.

Comment: @BulliedByMods I should be able to in a couple weeks. I just bought 15 lunch boxes. I opened 5 and got a santa suit. I'll open the rest in 2016 and report back if I get any Christmas themed items. Although that won't definitively answer the question about whether or not lunchboxes one receives *before* the "limited time" can have holiday themed items or not - I didn't have any to test that hypothesis.

Comment: I believe there was a post on reddit a while that made the case that they are selected at the time of purchase/award.  But I don't have it handy.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the contents of the lunch box are determined at the moment you earn it, not when you open it. I tested this on the PC version by making copies of the save file.

Initially, when I earned the lunch box, I would save the game and make a backup of the save file. Then I'd open the lunch box and note the contents. Then I'd exit the game (which automatically updates the save file), copy the backup to the expected name, e.g. "Vault1.sav", and restart the game. The lunch box contents were the same. I did this a few different times and the contents were always the same when re-using the save file made after earning the lunch box.

Then I started making backups just prior to earning the lunch box. If I didn't like the contents, I would exit, restore the save I made prior to earning the lunch box, restart, and would get different stuff.

It's very tedious, but sometimes worth it when all you get is some junk you already have plenty of.

Answer (score -3):

Limited time means it's an event so yes they will have the costumes.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?